# Allocating space for a reference returned

Tags: c++, pointers

I have created a function to calculate the difference of 2 timeval functions. Here is the basic version of that function.

```
struct timeval* getDifference(struct timeval* startTime, struct timeval* finishTime)
{
    struct timeval* difference = new struct timeval;
    difference->tv_sec = finishTime->tv_sec - startTime->tv_sec;
    difference->tv_usec = finishTime->tv_usec - startTime->tv_usec;
    return difference;
}

int main()
{
    struct timeval a,b;
    struct timeval* c;
    gettimeofday(&a, NULL);
    usleep(100000);
    gettimeofday(&b, NULL);

    c = getDifference(&a, &b);
 }
```

What i want to know is if the usage `struct timeval* c;` safe? or should it be like `struct timeval* c = new struct timeval;`?

If it is safe then would freeing `c` free the `difference = new struct timeval;` allocated inside the function?

Comment: If by freeing you mean doing `delete c;` then yes its safe, but if you mean `free(c);` then its not.

Comment: so what is the risk if i am using free() ?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan it's undefined behavior, because you allocated with `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan: See this FAQ for details: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not using pointers at all in your case. Let the arguments be references have the return be copied:

```
struct timeval getDifference(const struct timeval& startTime, const struct timeval& finishTime)
{
    struct timeval difference;
    difference.tv_sec = finishTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec;
    difference.tv_usec = finishTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;
    return difference;
}
```

Comment: And you can expect NRVO will be applied.

Comment: @nodakai and even if it isn't, it's a struct holding two integers.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe (in this case) and yes, it would free the memory allocated by `getDifference` (if you actually call `delete`).

However, you should get used to initializing your pointers to `NULL` - unless you can initialize them to some other value. For example, in the following case, the behavior is undefined:

```
struct timeval a,b;
struct timeval* c;
gettimeofday(&a, NULL);
usleep(100000);
gettimeofday(&b, NULL);
if ( someCondition )
    c = getDifference(&a, &b);
delete c;
```

If `someCondition` is false, you're deleting `c` which wasn't properly initialized. If it were initialized to `NULL`, the behavior is well defined (it does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's safe, because you are returning a pointer to already allocated struct. And yes, free-ing c will free struct you've allocated in the function. By the way, maybe a better choice would be allocating a struct outside the function and then pass a pointer to it, because you don't have to think about who allocated it and who is responsible for freeing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pointless and even harmful to call `struct timeval* c = new struct timeval;` before calling `c = getDifference(...);` because the call to `new` allocates memory that would then be lost when moving the `c` pointer to the return value of `getDifference`.

However, since `getDifference()` allocates its return value, it is up to the caller (the `main` function) to free the memory. So yes, you have to call `delete` on the return value of `getDifference`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's safe, but in general you'll want to avoid allocating memory in a function and free() it in another.

What I'd suggest is change the prototype our your `getDifference` function to take a pointer to the time difference:

```
int getDifference(struct timeval* startTime, struct timeval* finishTime, 
                  struct timeval *difference)
```

Now you could have your main act like this:

```
int getDifference(struct timeval* startTime, struct timeval* finishTime, struct timeval *difference)
{
    if( difference && startTime && finishTime) {
        difference->tv_sec = finishTime->tv_sec - startTime->tv_sec;
        difference->tv_usec = finishTime->tv_usec - startTime->tv_usec;
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    struct timeval a,b;
    struct timeval c;
    gettimeofday(&a, NULL);
    usleep(100000);
    gettimeofday(&b, NULL);

    if( getDifference(&a, &b, &c) == 0 )
    { 
        // success !!
    }
 }
```